# HTTPS and Force_SSL backend login problem

Tags: php, security, login, nginx

I recently upgraded my Joomla site to 3.3.1 from 3.2.2, upgraded the PHP version on my server from 5.3 to 5.5.14 and installed NGINX.

The upgrade went fine, a couple of minor styling and extension related problems but overall a nice smooth update. That was until I enabled $force_ssl on the backend only.

With this enabled the backend login screen simply flashes but proceeds no further. What i've tried to diagnose:

- Checked for server error logs - no related logs found
- Enabled PHP errors and Joomla debugging - nothing shown
- logging in from different browsers and machine's
- Clearing temp files on browsers
- clearing cache/ temp files on joomla site
- Downgrading PHP to 5.4.30
- Using Yireo SSL redirection plugin instead of joomla force_ssl

Here's the strangest thing - If I disable force_ssl, but direct the browser to  it will login fine, so just a problem with forcing SSL or the redirection Joomla's using?

Because I'm not the only one using the back end I can't rely on people going to the HTTPS:// address so really do need to have the ability to 'force' people to use SSL.

Now I'm running out of ideas - can anyone out there point me in the right direction?

Cheers!

Answer (score 2):

If troubleshooting Joomla takes too much time, then force ssl on admin using nginx. Something like

```
server {
    root /var/www/
    location / {
    }
    location /administrator {
        rewrite ^ https://$http_host$request_uri? permanent;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Marco, thats a good workaround, but if I can get it working properly that'd be preferable.